# Finding a general formula for an arithmetic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, education, arithmetic-progressions

How can I find the general formula to this arithmetic sequence?
$$\frac{-1}{4}, \frac{-1}{8}, \frac{-1}{12}, \frac{-1}{16}, \frac{-1}{20}, \frac{-1}{24}$$

I have noticed that firstly, they increase by four, and they are all multiples of four. I have some guesses on the general formula, but I am not sure.

Comment: Have you yet identified a pattern?

Comment: What do you notice about the numbers on the denominator? The _first_ has a $4$ on the bottom, the _second_ has an $8$ on the bottom, ..., the $n$th has a (what?) on the bottom.

Comment: yes, I have noticed that firstly they increase by four, and they are all multiples of four. I have some guesses on the general formula, however im am not sure.

Comment: $$-\frac1{4n}$$

Comment: how did you find this?

Comment: The denominators are all factors of four, as previously mentioned. So what else could I come up with? In the meantime, please don't be discouraged by the downvotes. This site has some quality standards for its questions that should be met. Please take a look at the help page about "how to ask a good question"

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE Tara. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and use the tips for formulating better questions in future, Good luck!

Comment: @Wesley welcome to MSE.  your comment describing what you have tried should be added to the question.  Only then it will fit the criteria for this site.

Comment: P.S. don't be put off by the down votes. Some users forget MSE is for mathematicians of all abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerators remain $-1$ throughout, the denominators go: $4,8,12,16,20,24...$, which are all multiples of $4$. In terms of spotting this, be sure to learn times tables to make it easier. Since they are all multiples of $4$, a general term is $4n$. Hence the general formula is $\frac{-1}{4n}$